# Nothing show in watches :S

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

I use codeblocks 12.11 and when I tray to debug program in watches nothing shows, i set normaly breakpoint and start debugger but in watches there is nothing. Any one know where is the problem ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Watches do not work and are not available in the stock Code::Blocks 12.11, although the watches window is there. They are back in C::B 13.12, so I suggest you upgrade. Get it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/).